# What are the possibilites to handle events that involve multiple components?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on a small project where i am writing a mobile first application.
For this i am planning to have a navbar at the top of the screen and a slide in menu on the left. I want these components to be avaiable on every page/view.

My current architecture is built like this:

```
<app-component>
 -> <navbar-component>
 -> <sidemenu-component>
 -> <router-outlet><!-- The different pages will be placed here !--></router-outlet>
```

Now i want to be able to click on a button in the `navbar-component` to open the `sidemenu-component`.

For this i will need a reference of the other component either in the sidemenu to register on the click event, or in the navbar to trigger the sidemenu.

My initial idea was to use the `@Input()` and `@Output()` properties to pass the references of the components.

```
//app-component.html
<navbar-component [parentComponent]="referenceToAppComponent" (instance)="navbarComponent"></navbar-component>
<sidemenu-component [parentComponent]="referenceToAppComponent" (instance)="sidemenuComponent"></sidemenu-component>
```

Comment: No, you dont need references to components. Just share a service between the two components, and emit events (using an observable) from this shared service. https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Comment: You might consider using the router to do this. You could use named Outlets and express the opening of the menu as a route itself, navigating to it by way of the nav bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Input, Output APIs** can be used when you have **parent/child** components. So using `Input`, *parent will send data to child and using `Output`, child can send data to parent*.

Now here, It seems that you deal with sibling component (not having parent/child scenario). For such type of sibling scenario, a **shared service** can be used.
 ***BUT MAKE SURE TO USE SINGLETON SHARED SERVICE***.
 Singleton shared service will share a single instance of the service throughout the app and so you can communicate among sibling components.

**More detail : https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction**